# Set/Change user password through netsuite RESTlet script

Tags: javascript, passwords, netsuite, suitescript

I'm integrating a WordPress site with a client's NetSuite using RESTlet scripts in SuiteScript.  It's been going pretty well until I got to the reset password part.  When a user change's their password in WordPress I'd like to update their password for NetSuite as well.

I figured I could use the nlapiSubmitRecord and update the record with a new pass but I don't see anywhere that talks about a password field.  I'm assuming there's some functionality I don't know about or maybe it's just not possible to do through a RESTlet script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick glance through the docs, and I see this is available in 2.0.  Check out the ([N/auth Module](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4296360422.html)) and the [auth.changePassword Method](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4298157647.html).

They also included some demo code that show how to change the current user's email and password:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['N/auth'],function(auth){
  function changeEmailAndPassword() {
    var password='myCurrentPassword';
    auth.changeEmail({
      password:password,
      newEmail:'auth_test@newemail.com'
    });
    auth.changePassword({
      currentPassword:password,
      newPassword:'myNewPa55Word'
    });
  }
  changeEmailAndPassword();
});
```